# Formatting for many currencies

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Does anyone know a clever way to conditional format for multiple currencies? I know that I could use conditional formatting formulas and program all those in, however, I have 154 currencies to format for. I wonder if there is a VBA solution or some other clever solution you've used in the past. Thanks!

Comment: I'm with @Dave here - what are your current conditional formatting rules? Or formulas? Or VBA? Help us help you.

Comment: It is a unclear exactly what you are trying to format and how. Are you trying to format the data, i.e. the currency symbol? Or are you trying to change the color of text or fill depending on the currency?

Comment: The first part asks for conditional formatting,  then vba. So the question is unclear. It's also to broad. It also reads like a "do my work for me" question. I'm sure it isn't so please edit your question to show what you've done, this way we can help you 

Comment: We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, this should get you started.

```
Sub Macro1()
' I will assume you have something like "GBP", "USD", in column D. Next to that cell is a currency amount.
' This will look at the cell in column D, and apply the appropriate format.

Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Set rng = Range("E1:E10")
For Each cel In rng
    Select Case cel.Offset(0, -1).Value
    Case "USD"
        cel.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
    Case "GBP"
        cel.NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"
    End Select
Next cel

End Sub
```

It's not conditional formatting, but may run a little quicker.  If you want it to be conditional formatting, let me know and I can tweak it.  You should see how you can add more currencies.  If you have some other way to determine which currency a cell should be, let me know and I can update this. But also, please update your OP with any formulas/macros you have already, and any more detail on which currencies you want to use.